# Fix 'this authentication plugin is not supported' when trying to connect with MySQL

Tags: mysql, go

Getting this error when go application is trying to connect with MySQL 8

Answer (score 1):

This error is coming because MySQL increases its security level in a new version. It has changed its default authentication plugin from `mysql_native_password` to `caching_sha2_password`.

The workaround to resolve this issue is

1. First locate your `my.cnf` file location using below command.

```
mysql --help | grep "Default options" -A 1
```

2. Then update `my.cnf` , using below lines

```
[mysqld]

# Only allow connections from localhost

bind-address = 127.0.0.1

**default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password** // add this line
```

3. cd /usr/local/bin
4. mysql.server stop
5. mysql.server start

This will solve your issue :)